# Multiple IPs tieing to domains in sendmail

Tags: sendmail

I am going to have multiple IP addresses pointing to a single Linode. I will then be setting up reverse DNS pointing to each IP address.

What I would like to know is how do I configure sendmail so that email from:

mydomain.com comes from IP: 1234/mydomain.com

Whilst email from

myotherdomain.com comes from IP: 5678/myotherdomain.com

Is this something to do with masquerading?

Comment: So you mean that you want to send emails from different IP's depending on wich domain you are sending with? Why?

Comment: Why not? RDNS lookup is an anti-spam feature and I'm hosting multiple websites.

Comment: My question was, why do you want different IP's to be used depending on which domain are used when sending an email? I did not ask about reversedns.

Comment: Ah - because of reverse dns which cannot tie multiple domains to an IP address

Comment: I still dont get why you want to do it. You do not need it to send mail from different domains from the same server. Just specify the IP in SPF and you are good.

Comment: How do you want to submit the emails? a) local command line sendmail b) via SMTP from another host c) other way